# ¿Cómo eliminar un paquete composer?

Tags: composer

Tengo un proyecto Laravel y al comienzo tuve la necesidad de instalar este [paquete](https://github.com/thinhbuzz/laravel-google-captcha), pero después de un día y medio y sin resultados para que funcione decidí que no lo usaría.

En fin, quiero removerlo de mi proyecto laravel. Busqué la manera y al parecer es con:

```
composer remove vendor/buzz/laravel-google-captcha
```

Y después un `composer update` y quedaría listo, pero al parecer no, veo mi composer.json y encuentro en el `require` el nombre del paquete. **¿Esta eliminado el paquete correctamente?**

Si no está correctamente eliminado, ¿cual sería la manera correcta?

Cuando ejecuté el *composer remove* en la consola este fue el resultado que arrojó:

```
Loading composer repositories wit
Updating dependencies (including

  [Composer\Repository\Repository
  The contents of https://repo.pa
  9217615cfe1694944ba41769e969c5b
  signature. This could indicate
   software corrupting files. Try
  ou think it is a mistake.

update [--prefer-source] [--prefe
 [--no-custom-installers] [--no-a
-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [
[-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--
ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-s
root-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con el mismo paquete y funcionó perfectamente la desinstalación con `composer remove ...`

Comment: @Shaz Mmm que raro, y no te deja en el `composer.json` el nombre del paquete?

Comment: Correcto, no lo deja.

Comment: ¿Podría ser un problema de permisos?
prueba con sudo

Answer (score 0):

Agregando el comando `--update-with-dependencies` al final del *remove* actualiza todo de una misma vez, los .... (punto punto punto punto) es la dependencia a desinstalar.

```
composer remove .... --update-with-dependencies
```

Comment: Listo, gracias por la orientación

Answer (score 0):

Este es un ejemplo completo del error que sale en tu consola.

```
The contents of https://repo.packagist.org/p/phpunit/phpunit%2409ce48554409f24a1144e25d466169aaf1eab60b5ca98df75998dd2cf14db9d4.json do not match its signature. This could indicate a man-in-the-middle attack or e.g. antivirus software corrupting files. Try running composer again and report this if you think it is a mistake.
```

Básicamente te dice que los archivos en tu computadora no concuerdan con lo que está en el servidor, y es posible que tu antivirus esté modificando los archivos.

Intenta deshabilitar tu antivirus mientras realizas esta operación, así como cualquier otro software que sospeches que podría estar causando este inconveniente.

Por cierto, para desinstalar una dependencia no es necesario que especifiques la carpeta `vendor` al inicio del nombre del paquete:

```sh
composer remove buzz/laravel-google-captcha
```